# unable to fetch a get request and print the output using fetch api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, fetch, fetch-api

I am using react to get the data from an API using fetch API and print it but i was unable to retrieve data from after doing a fetch request. Here is the code[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-banzai-xuzfty?file=/src/App.js). The input should be `CC(C)(C)Br` and the output is `success` message

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

export default function App() {
  const [solutestate, setSolutestate] = useState("");
  const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState("");
  console.log(solutestate);
  console.log(fetchData);

  let params = new URLSearchParams({
    solute: solutestate
  });

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    fetch(
      `https://fastapi-n7b7u.app/predict_two?${params}`,
      {
        method: "GET"
      }
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setFetchData(result);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
        <form noValidate onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <div>
            Input: CC(C)(C)Br
            <TextField
              label="Solute"
              variant="outlined"
              onChange={(e) => setSolutestate(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button variant="contained">Submit</Button>
            <TextField label="Result" variant="outlined" value={fetchData} />
          </div>
        </form>
      </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues here.

1. Your submit button is not of type submit, so submit method is never called.
2. You will also want to put a preventDefault() on your submit handler, as the default will reload the page.

so changes are->

```
<Button type="submit" variant="contained">Submit</Button>
```

and

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch(.....
```

[Updated Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-banzai-xuzfty?file=/src/App.js:395-458)

> ps.  This is not specifically about React, this is how forms work in
> HTML.

Answer (score -1):

```
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
  let params = new URLSearchParams({
    solute: solutestate
  });
    fetch(
      `https://fastapi-ihub-n7b7u.ondigitalocean.app/predict_two?${params}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        content-type : "application/json"
      }
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setFetchData(result);
      });
  };
```